# About the position of the added view after calling WindowManager.addView()

Tags: android, android-windowmanager

Here is the problem~ I tried to add an ImageView to the window by calling the WindowManager.addView() method. But I found that the ImageView is in the center of the screen, not the left-top corner. It appears in left-top corner only when I set the gravity property of the WindowManager.LayoutParams to Gravity.LEFT|Gravity.TOP, why? Is the default value of gravity property Gravity.CENTER? I looked into the android source code but got lost.

```
    ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
    img.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_delete);
    WindowManager manager = (WindowManager) this.getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(60,60,WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS|WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE|WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    //params.gravity= Gravity.LEFT|Gravity.TOP;
    manager.addView(img, params);
```

In the source code of WindowManager.LayoutParams, I found that only when the gravity is set, the x and y properties will be taken into account:

```
    /**
     * X position for this window.  With the default gravity it is ignored.
     * When using {@link Gravity#LEFT} or {@link Gravity#START} or {@link Gravity#RIGHT} or
     * {@link Gravity#END} it provides an offset from the given edge.
     */
    @ViewDebug.ExportedProperty
    public int x;

    /**
     * Y position for this window.  With the default gravity it is ignored.
     * When using {@link Gravity#TOP} or {@link Gravity#BOTTOM} it provides
     * an offset from the given edge.
     */
    @ViewDebug.ExportedProperty
    public int y;
```

However this is not enough, I want to konw what happens when gravity is not set(More specifically, I want to find the code drawing the ImageView).

Any tip will be appreciated.

Comment: most likely `TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT` causes that

Comment: But can you find the source code dealing with this properties(gravity,x,y,type and so on)? I got lost when I was reading the source code

Comment: tried `TYPE_PHONE`? like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26698965/2252830)

Comment: I tried and the imageview still in the center of the sreen,,,

Answer (score 0):

I guess this leads to:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT
```

Comment: I agree with you but I cannot find the corresponding source code